# How do I display a text when hovering on another text?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to display a text when hovering on another text but it is not working. I followed every steps on another similar questions but it is still not working

Code:

```
.text-mada {
    width: 18%;
    position: relative;
    left: 760px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 15px;
    
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 750px;
    display: none;
    
}
```

```
.dot-mada {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    left: 52px;
    bottom: 44px;
```

```
.dot-mada:hover + .text-mada {display: block}
```

My goal is that when `.dot-mada` is hovered, `.text-mada` is displayed

PS: I'm a begginner so this might be a dumb question for you guys, lol

Comment: Please show us your HTML. From the CSS I see you are assuming that the text div is immediate sibling of the hovered element. Is it?

Comment: It is `.dot-mada:hover ~  .text-mada {display: block}` you have to use the `~` not the `+`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

keep the div you want to show, below the visible div

Comment: This is a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: Uhh sorry. First time commenting/answering here

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like in this example:

```css
div {
height:100px;width:100px;
background:blue;
margin:20px;
}

span {
display:none;
height:100px;width:100px;
background:pink;
margin:20px;
}

div:hover ~ span {
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>text 1</div>
<span>text 2</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `.text-mada` is inside `.dot-mada`, then the solution looks like this

```css
.text-mada {
    display: none;
}

.dot-mada:hover > .text-mada {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dot-mada">
    Foo
    <span class="text-mada">Bar</span>
</div>
```

If they are siblings:

```css
.text-mada {
    display: none;
}

.dot-mada:hover + .text-mada {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="dot-mada">Foo</span>
<span class="text-mada">Bar</span>
```